# Articles providing informal discussions on major developments on a particular problem?

Tags: soft-question

Some time ago, when I was studying the Kervaire-Milnor paper ([Groups of Homotopy Spheres I](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970128)), I found the following survey article very helpful in guiding my studies:

[Milnor, Differential Topology 46 Years Later.](https://www.ams.org/notices/201106/rtx110600804p.pdf)

The informality of the article was very helpful. It gave me a quick overview on what has already been done in the field, as well as why the well-known results are so important. As someone new to differential topology, the article served as an excellent guide for navigating further readings.

**My Question.** Are there other geometry/topology articles of a similar flavor, namely:

1. Provides an informal discussion on the major developments of a problem between now and when it was first posed.
2. Provides references to said developments.

Comment: I use mainly two tools when searching for this kind of information: My network (or mathoverflow) and Mathreviews/Zentralblatt (get a reasonable entry point and apply a human approximation of Googles algorithm to the network of citations (going forward and backward in time). After some time, very good and carefully written papers/books often get attention).

Answer (score 3):

Benjamin McKay, *[Summary of progress on the Blaschke conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1326)*.
Sorry for tooting my own horn.